# SqlDataReader GetBoolean from Calculated Resultset Field

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

I've got a field in my SQL SPROC resultset that is a calculated CASE statement that returns 1 or 0 (ie True/False).

When I try to use the GetBoolean method of the SqlDataReader class and exception gets thrown.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What kind of exception? Any message text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the value into a `bit` before returning it

```
CAST (value AS bit)
```